# Pivot dataframe with duplicate index by aggregating per group

Tags: python, pandas

I am facing the following dataframe.

|  | Date | Security | Field | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-05-03 08:00:12.394000 | CFI2Z2 | VALUE | 83.3 |
| 1 | 2022-05-03 08:00:12.394000 | CFI2Z2 | VOLUME | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-05-03 08:00:12.460000 | TRNLTTFFVMc1 | VALUE | 83.4 |
| 3 | 2022-05-03 08:00:12.460000 | TRNLTTFFVMc1 | VOLUME | 1 |
| 4 | 2022-05-03 08:00:12.460000 | TRNLTTFFVMc1 | VALUE | 83.23 |
| 3 | 2022-05-03 08:00:12.460000 | TRNLTTFFVMc1 | VOLUME | 2 |

Note that the column "Date" is not unique. Neither globally or and not per group.

I am trying to achieve the following transformation.

|  | ('TRNLTTFFVMc1', 'VALUE') | ('TRNLTTFFVMc1', 'VOLUME') | ('CFI2Z2', 'VALUE') | ('CFI2Z2', 'VOLUME') |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-03 08:00:12.394000 | nan | nan | 83.3 | 1 |
| 2022-05-03 08:00:12.460000 | 83,27 | 3 | nan | nan |

Note that the output columns index is a MultiIndex.

```
MultiIndex([('TRNLTTFFVMc1',  'VALUE'),
            ('TRNLTTFFVMc1', 'VOLUME'),
            (      'CFI2Z2',  'VALUE'),
            (      'CFI2Z2', 'VOLUME')],
           )
```

For groups with multiple VOLUME/PRICE pairs I would like to calculate the Volume-Weighted Average Price.

The problem is that I can't just pivot, because the date is not unique. I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: You said you want the volume-weighted average price and I guess you want to sum the volume as in the example? How would you identify the value-volume pairs since the dates and security are duplicated? Do you assume them to come one after another in the index?

Comment: Yes, I assume they (Volume, Price) come pairwise. Unfortunately the raw data has no identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the brief discussion, here is my answer. I tried to make it more concise but I could not. If someone has a better option, I'm all ears!

Here is the data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Date': pd.to_datetime(['2022-05-03 08:00:12.394000', '2022-05-03 08:00:12.394000', 
                             '2022-05-03 08:00:12.460000', '2022-05-03 08:00:12.460000', 
                             '2022-05-03 08:00:12.460000', '2022-05-03 08:00:12.460000']),
     'Security': ['CFI2Z2', 'CFI2Z2', 'TRNLTTFFVMc1', 'TRNLTTFFVMc1', 'TRNLTTFFVMc1', 'TRNLTTFFVMc1'],
     'Field': ['VALUE', 'VOLUME', 'VALUE', 'VOLUME', 'VALUE', 'VOLUME'],
     'Value': [83.3, 1, 83.4, 1, 83.23, 2]
    }
)
```

```
                     Date      Security   Field  Value
0 2022-05-03 08:00:12.394        CFI2Z2   VALUE  83.30
1 2022-05-03 08:00:12.394        CFI2Z2  VOLUME   1.00
2 2022-05-03 08:00:12.460  TRNLTTFFVMc1   VALUE  83.40
3 2022-05-03 08:00:12.460  TRNLTTFFVMc1  VOLUME   1.00
4 2022-05-03 08:00:12.460  TRNLTTFFVMc1   VALUE  83.23
5 2022-05-03 08:00:12.460  TRNLTTFFVMc1  VOLUME   2.00
```

First, calculate the aggregate values for each `(Date, Security)` pair:

```
def calculate_aggregates(fields):
    avg_val = (np.sum(fields[0::2]*fields[1::2]))/(tot:=np.sum(fields[1::2]))
    return (avg_val, tot)

values = np.concatenate(df.groupby(['Date', 'Security']).apply(lambda df: calculate_aggregates(df['Value'].to_numpy())))
```

Then, assign the values to each of the groups and unstack the index twice to create the desired column `MultiIndex`:

```
df_result = df.groupby(['Date', 'Field', 'Security']).first().assign(Value=values).unstack(-1).unstack(-1)
```

Then, `df_result` is:

```
Security                CFI2Z2        TRNLTTFFVMc1       
Field                    VALUE VOLUME        VALUE VOLUME
Date                                                     
2022-05-03 08:00:12.394   83.3    1.0          NaN    NaN
2022-05-03 08:00:12.460    NaN    NaN    83.286667    3.0
```

The assumption this code makes to calculate the aggregates is that the `(VALUE, VOLUME)` pairs are coming always in this order within the groups. It could be changed with some checks in the `groupby` function if this is not the case.

Comment: @jezrael thanks, yeah I know `pivot_table`, but I don't think you can easily compute the volume-weighted average with `aggfunc` as OP asks?

Comment: Now understand. Added solution.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with `MultiIndex Series`, working well if all pairs with `VOLUME` and `VALUE` per columns `Date,Security`.

```
#created Multiindex Series
s = df.set_index(['Date','Security', 'Field'])['Value']

#selected rows by values in level2 
VAL = s.xs('VALUE', level=2)
VOL = s.xs('VOLUME', level=2)

#count VOLUMEs
COUNT = VOL.groupby(level=[0,1]).sum()

#because pairs multiply working, divide sum and append VOL like new column
#then reshape and swap MultiIndex in columns
df = (VAL.mul(VOL)
         .groupby(level=[0,1]).sum().div(COUNT).to_frame('VALUE')
         .assign(VOLUME=COUNT)
         .unstack()
         .swaplevel(0,1,axis=1)
         .sort_index(axis=1))
print (df)
Security                CFI2Z2        TRNLTTFFVMc1       
                         VALUE VOLUME        VALUE VOLUME
Date                                                     
2022-05-03 08:00:12.394   83.3    1.0          NaN    NaN
2022-05-03 08:00:12.460    NaN    NaN    83.286667    3.0
```

**Details**:

```
print ((VAL.index == VOL.index).all())
True

print (VAL.mul(VOL))
Date                     Security    
2022-05-03 08:00:12.394  CFI2Z2           83.30
2022-05-03 08:00:12.460  TRNLTTFFVMc1     83.40
                         TRNLTTFFVMc1    166.46
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```